# How to stretch an object?

Tags: ios, swift, cgfloat

I have a `UIMapView` and a small area for banner ads. I want to stretch the `UIMapView` 50 pixels when ads are removed.

I tried the following line but I couldn't convert CGFloat to float value.

```
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(mapView.origin.x, mapView.origin.y, mapView.frame.width, (Float(mapView.frame.height)+50))
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code and it will work for you:

```
self.map.frame = CGRect(x: map.frame.origin.x, y: map.frame.origin.y, width: map.frame.width, height: map.frame.height + 50)
```